# Trying to dual boot Linux Mint Cinammon 19 with Windows 10 but Linux Install does not recognize Windows OS

Tags: linux-mint, partition, dual-boot

I've been trying to dualboot my system (XPS 13 9350) with pre-installed Windows 10. I get as far as booting Linux Mint from the onetime boot menu but after that I have trouble installing Linux because I do not see the "install alongside windows" option.

I am certain that I have Legacy OS enabled so that cannot be the issue. I tried to do fixparts but I stopped because my system's partition table is in gpt and apparently that's a no-no. Is there something I can do to have Linux recognize Windows?

Attached below is the output from running sudo blkd and sudo parted -l

---

```
mint@mint:~$ sudo parted -l
Model:  USB DISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 8054MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8054MB  8053MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Warning: failed to translate partition name
Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      525MB   660MB  134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      660MB   242GB  242GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      242GB   243GB  1020MB  ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 5      243GB   256GB  12.7GB  ntfs                                       hidden, diag


mint@mint:~$ sudo blkid 
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="2C0E-14D3" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="7160c180-c590-45de-8edf-e85cd06f4de6"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="OS" UUID="7EDC41A4DC415793" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c50785ae-3eb5-47e5-934b-0d371c4219c0"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="WINRETOOLS" UUID="92F431BDF431A3FF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="140d5cb9-419a-456b-9cc4-d8e3a983a87a"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="Image" UUID="225232095231E269" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7f261049-8984-4da6-9655-ba87e6f740e0"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="LINUX MINT" UUID="88BE-6FA1" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="006641ea-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="b2b0ad84-c308-43b9-a5d7-8c92b74ac659" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="fa1fd07f-ede4-439c-9919-61df3d11f13e"
```

Comment: Since you have an EFI system, have you tried NOT using the Legacy OS option? The output of `sudo blkid` indicates you have a Linux Mint partition. Is that from another installation? I'm not clear on what you mean by "trouble installing Linux".

Comment: You cannot dual boot with one operating system in EFI mode and the other in BIOS mode. They must be in the same mode; either both in EFI mode or both in BIOS mode.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa The "Linux Mint" is my live USB. It was renamed to that once I used rufus magic on it. I can load Linux Mint using the USB but I cannot permanently install it on my laptop as a second operating system.

Comment: @AlexP Which one is in EFI and which one in BIOS? Where do I look to see this information?

Comment: I cannot accept your suggestion in the comments as an answer, @EmmanuelRosa, but disabling Legacy OS and booting through UEFI helped Linux recognize my Windows OS. Thank you